# is it possible to install Ubuntu / iso via a local hard disk with no OS?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, kubuntu-netbook

My netbook doesn't come with a CD/DVD player and I do not have a thumb drive either (I'm located at rural area).

OS is broken and formatted,not I have a blank HDD with no OS,no CD player or thumb drive.

any idea how do I install ubuntu/kubuntu?

oh my netbook comes with an SD card reader and I have a working one.

Answer (score 1):

Then its simple! You need to get a micro SD / SD Card , and put the iso on your SD card just like a normal USB HDD!

You can use pendrivelinux.com or normal terminal `dd if="" of="" bs="512k"` cmd but its very sensitive command so better to use something like pendrivelinux or unetbootin!

Then go to Boot menu and normally your device be listed else use USB HDD one!